# How should I change this function such that it can neatly handle strings and unicode in both Python 2 and in Python 3?

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode

I have a function that sends text messages and files to a recipient or recipients. There is a global sender object that accepts text and recipient configurations as unicode objects in Python 2 and as string objects in Python 3. Here is the function as it is right now and is compatible with Python 2:

```
def send_message_Telegram(
    recipient  = None, # string
    recipients = None, # list of strings
    text       = None,
    filepath   = None
    ):

    if text and not filepath:
        if recipient:
            tg_sender.send_msg(
                unicode(recipient),
                unicode(text)
            )
        if recipients:
            for recipient in recipients:
                tg_sender.send_msg(
                    unicode(recipient),
                    unicode(text)
                )
    if filepath and not text:
        if recipient:
            tg_sender.send_file(
                unicode(recipient),
                unicode(filepath)
            )
        if recipients:
            for recipient in recipients:
                tg_sender.send_file(
                    unicode(recipient),
                    unicode(filepath)
                )
```

If I want this function to be compatible with Python 3, I have to change all the uses of `unicode()` to `str()`. I need the function to work in both Python 2 and Python 3, so how should it be changed? I don't want to write code like this all over the place:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    tg_sender.send_msg(
        str(recipient),
        str(text)
    )
else:
    tg_sender.send_msg(
        unicode(recipient),
        unicode(text)
    )
```

Like, this is the best I've got right now, but it seems weird:

```
def ustr(text):

    if text is not None:
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
            return str(text)
        else:
            return unicode(text)
    else:
        return text

def send_message_Telegram(
    recipient  = None, # string
    recipients = None, # list of strings
    text       = None,
    filepath   = None
    ):

    if text and not filepath:
        if recipient:
            tg_sender.send_msg(
                ustr(recipient),
                ustr(text)
            )
        if recipients:
            for recipient in recipients:
                tg_sender.send_msg(
                    ustr(recipient),
                    ustr(text)
                )
    if filepath and not text:
        if recipient:
            tg_sender.send_file(
                ustr(recipient),
                ustr(filepath)
            )
        if recipients:
            for recipient in recipients:
                tg_sender.send_file(
                    ustr(recipient),
                    ustr(filepath)
                )
```

Comment: You might take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a function to safely cast the string.

This would be my solution:

```
def string(data):
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
        return str(data)
    else:
        return unicode(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about an alias for the function depending on the version?:

```
def send_message_Telegram(recipient  = None, 
                          recipients = None, 
                          text = None,
                          filepath = None):
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        func = unicode
    else:
        func = str

    # the rest here, using 'func()'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [the `six` module](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) installed, you can use its `text_type` to refer to `unicode` in 2.x and `str` in 3.x.